# Record not created as debug log reports

Tags: trigger, debugging

In my sandbox I am debugging a Web-to-Lead issue that has to do with the custom Lead trigger code. I have a trigger handler that get's called after lead insert. The handler does a few things like creating a new Account and Case record. When I run my lead test class all the tests pass and the records are created as expected. However when I do a test web-to-lead post, no errors are reported in the browser or in the debug log, but the records are not created. Some excerpts from the debug log that indicate that the records were created are:

```
08:14:52.189 (189585256)|METHOD_ENTRY|[36]|01p18000000DBJy|LeadTriggerHandler.postProcessInsert(Lead)
08:14:52.189 (189684839)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[41]|String.valueOf(Object)
08:14:52.189 (189735694)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[41]|String.valueOf(Object)
08:14:52.189 (189773735)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[41]|System.debug(ANY)
08:14:52.189 (189787753)|USER_DEBUG|[41]|DEBUG|##*** New lead: 00Q18000001RfrzEAC
08:14:52.189 (189797840)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[41]|System.debug(ANY)
08:14:52.189 (189924877)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[46]|System.debug(ANY)
08:14:52.189 (189952704)|USER_DEBUG|[46]|DEBUG|##*** lead status is open and Email is: jj@example.com
```

The problem goes away if I uninstall the Salesforce for Social Media app. I can only assume there is some conflict between the managed app and my own custom lead trigger code, but how can I debug the conflict if the debug log report is not reliable?

Comment: Is it possible that the Salesforce for Social Media app does some kind of duplicate checks which delete your lead before you can see it?

Comment: That is certainly possible, but: *1.* the DML operations logged in the debug log doesn't indicate any record deletions and *2*. the account and case record that is reported as being created is also missing and how/why would the Social Media app delete those records?

Comment: Well you might try selecting the ID you get in your debug log with an "ALL ROWS" select statement (which also queries for deleted records). See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_query_all_rows.htm for details. If you find something, you know for sure that the records are created and then deleted.

Comment: Thanks @Off, Querying the recycle bin (QueryAll via the API) confirms that the missing records are not there.